# HttpClient Calls in PCL not working in iOS

Tags: ios, rest, http, xamarin, client

I'm experienced in Android/iOS/C# but new to Xamarin/VS for Mac to start here...

I have two projects in my solution. An iOS app project and a PCL.
Hoping to be able to write my networking/REST layer in the PCL.

I'm having a whole bunch of runtime problems with it though.  Here is what code in my PCL looks like.

```
        public static OverwatchAPI CreateClient(HttpClient c)
        {
            var shared = new OverwatchAPI
            {
                client = c
            };
            return shared;
        }

        public async Task<Stats> GetStats(string username)
        {
            var stats = new Stats();
            var uri = new Uri(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", baseURL, "/stats/xbl/us/", username));
            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                stats = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Stats>(content);
            }
            return stats;
        }
```

In my iOS project I'm setting it up as follows.

```
    OverwatchAPI api = OverwatchAPI.CreateClient(new HttpClient(new CFNetworkHandler()));
    ...
    public Stats GetStats(string playerName)
    {
        Stats stats = api.GetStats(playerName).Result;
        return stats;
    }
```

It just hangs on the api.GetStats and I can't figure out why or what to look at in order to further investigate this issue.  Nor do I know what question to ask myself in order to better reason with it.

Stuck. Any pointers would be great - Thanks!

Comment: What does the Uri looks like once all the string parts are concatenated?

Comment: https://obscure-bastion-80773.herokuapp.com/stats/xbl/us/Krivanka1 which works fine as a curl

Comment: Your problem seems to be with the `.Result`. Looks like a thread deadlock. Where are you calling `GetStats` method?

Comment: I'm calling it as part of viewDidAppear in the iOS app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `async` & `await` to get the Task's `Result` instead of accessing the property. Making async methods run synchronously blocks the UI thread which you definitely do not want in a mobile APP (the call to the REST service might take a second or two and for that time the UI would be blocked)

To make use of `async / await` You'll have to adjust your iOS method to return a `Task<Stats>` just like your PCL method.

Comment: Modified the method to as follows.   


    `public async void GetStats(string playerName)
    {
        var stats = await api.GetStats(playerName);
        Console.WriteLine("Stats: {0}", stats.ToString());
   }`